newtxmath disrupting bbold
I'm trying to use the packages newtxmath for a Times-like font together with bbold for a blackboard-bold alphabet which I like, but the two seem to collide. E.g. in several displays I have instances \mathbf{E} appearing in standard bold and blackboard-bold.
Here is my preamble, with all of the packages and commands defined.
%%% DOCUMENT %%%
\documentclass[letterpaper,leqno,11pt]{article}

%%% PACKAGES %%%
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\allowdisplaybreaks[1]
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={RoyalPurple},citecolor={RoyalPurple},urlcolor={Orchid}} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


%%% COUNTERS AND THEOREMS %%%
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rmk}{Remark}
\newtheorem{attempt}{Attempt}[section]

%%% TITLE %%%
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
%\textsc{\large{\@title}} \vskip 10pt
%\hskip 5pt \@date \\
%\hskip 5pt \@author \vskip 20pt
%}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\section}{\vskip25pt\centering\normalfont\large\sc}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\vskip10pt\normalfont\normalsize\it}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}

%%% COMMANDS %%%
\newcommand{\rd}{{\rm d}}
\newcommand{\re}{{\rm e}}
\newcommand{\ri}{{\rm i}}
\newcommand{\rN}{{\rm N}}
\newcommand{\rP}{{\rm P}}
\newcommand{\cA}{\mathscr{A}}
\newcommand{\cC}{\mathscr{C}}
\newcommand{\cD}{\mathscr{D}}
\newcommand{\cE}{\mathscr{E}}
\newcommand{\cF}{\mathscr{F}}
\newcommand{\cH}{\mathscr{H}}
\newcommand{\cP}{\mathscr{P}}
\newcommand{\cS}{\mathscr{S}}
\newcommand{\cZ}{\mathscr{Z}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\HH}{\mathbb{H}}
\newcommand{\EE}{{\bf E}}
\newcommand{\PP}{{\bf P}}
\newcommand{\TT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\pd}{\partial}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\Ups}{\Upsilon}
\newcommand{\ups}{\upsilon}
\newcommand{\fZ}{\mathfrak{Z}}
\renewcommand{\Re}{{\rm Re}}
\renewcommand{\Im}{{\rm Im}}
\newcommand{\sgn}{{\rm sgn}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbb{1}}

\renewcommand{\hat}{\widehat}
\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}
\newcommand{\und}{\underline}
\newcommand{\lV}{\lVert}
\newcommand{\rV}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\la}{\langle}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}
\newcommand{\wick}[1]{\hskip-1pt:\hskip-2pt#1\hskip-2pt:\hskip-1pt}
\newcommand{\norm}[2]{\lVert #1\rVert_{#2}}
\newcommand{\bignorm}[2]{\Big\lVert #1\Big\rVert_{#2}}
\newcommand{\ja}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle} %japanese brackets
\newcommand{\bigja}[1]{\Big\langle #1 \Big\rangle} 
\newcommand{\innerprod}[3]{\langle #1,#2 \rangle_{#3}}
\newcommand{\biginnerprod}[3]{\Big\langle #1,#2 \Big\rangle_{#3}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wlim}{w-lim}

\begin{document}

%
\begin{align*}
    &\EE\Big[\int_{\TT^d} f(x)\,\rd x\Big] \\
    &\EE\Big[\int f(x)\,\rd x\Big]
\end{align*}
%

\end{document}

Has anyone had similar issues? Any ideas how to fix this? I am not too familiar with latex but have already been muddling for a while and cannot seem to find similar enough issues online. Thanks in advance.

Do you really need all that code to demonstrate your problem?

Plus \bf and \rm has been out of date for more than 30years, use \mathbf and \mathrm

Try dropping latexsym no-one needs that one anyway. And do you really need gensymb

I would not use mathptmx at all. use \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}, that seems to be a better combo. With all of your many packages, my guess is that you are runing out of available math alphabets and things then start to do strange things. latexsym uses an entire alphabet for like 8 chars. So not worth it.

If I completely remove mathptmx and add newtxtext then it all works even with latexsymb loaded. Yet another example why one should leave mathptmx out.

Since you load amssymb, there can be no (rational) justification for loading latexsym. And you should definitely not use either \rm or \bf in any macro definitions. Assuming that \EE is supposed to represent the expectations operator, it's simply wrong to write \newcommand{\EE}{{\bf E}}. Instead, you should be writing \DeclareMathOperator{\EE}{\mathbf{E}}.

You should first of all fix your preamble:

remove mathptmx, which is a 25-year-old hack and makes no sense together with newtx;

latexsym should never be used with documents less than 30 years old;

commands such as \rm and \bf have been deprecated for 30 years; see how to correctly redefine \Re and \Im in the code below;

the chances you need gensymb are pretty slim;

amssymb should not be loaded along with newtxmath;

if you load float for the [H] option, don't;

you want \Bigl and \Bigr, not \Big;

redefining \hat to be \widehat and \bar to be \overline is asking for bad typography, in my opinion.


\documentclass[letterpaper,leqno,11pt]{article}

%%% PACKAGES %%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed

\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,]{biblatex}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={RoyalPurple},
  citecolor={RoyalPurple},
  urlcolor={Orchid}
}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

%%% COUNTERS AND THEOREMS %%%
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rmk}{Remark}
\newtheorem{attempt}{Attempt}[section]

%%% Sectional command
\titleformat{\section}{\vskip25pt\centering\normalfont\large\sc}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\vskip10pt\normalfont\normalsize\it}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}

%%% COMMANDS %%%
\newcommand{\rd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\re}{\mathrm{e}}
\newcommand{\ri}{\mathrm{i}}
\newcommand{\rN}{\mathrm{N}}
\newcommand{\rP}{\mathrm{P}}
\newcommand{\cA}{\mathscr{A}}
\newcommand{\cC}{\mathscr{C}}
\newcommand{\cD}{\mathscr{D}}
\newcommand{\cE}{\mathscr{E}}
\newcommand{\cF}{\mathscr{F}}
\newcommand{\cH}{\mathscr{H}}
\newcommand{\cP}{\mathscr{P}}
\newcommand{\cS}{\mathscr{S}}
\newcommand{\cZ}{\mathscr{Z}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\HH}{\mathbb{H}}
\newcommand{\EE}{\mathbf{E}}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbf{P}}
\newcommand{\TT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\pd}{\partial}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\Ups}{\Upsilon}
\newcommand{\ups}{\upsilon}
\newcommand{\fZ}{\mathfrak{Z}}

\let\Re\relax\let\Im\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbb{1}}

\renewcommand{\hat}{\widehat}
\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}
\newcommand{\und}{\underline}
\newcommand{\lV}{\lVert}
\newcommand{\rV}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\la}{\langle}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}
\newcommand{\wick}[1]{\hskip-1pt:\hskip-2pt#1\hskip-2pt:\hskip-1pt}
\newcommand{\norm}[2]{\lVert #1\rVert_{#2}}
\newcommand{\bignorm}[2]{\Bigl\lVert #1\Bigr\rVert_{#2}}
\newcommand{\ja}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle} %japanese brackets
\newcommand{\bigja}[1]{\Bigl\langle #1 \Bigr\rangle} 
\newcommand{\innerprod}[3]{\langle #1,#2 \rangle_{#3}}
\newcommand{\biginnerprod}[3]{\Bigl\langle #1,#2 \Bigr\rangle_{#3}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wlim}{w-lim}

\allowdisplaybreaks[1]

\begin{document}

This is text with math bold letters $\mathbb{A}\mathbb{b}\mathbb{c}$
\begin{align*}
    &\EE\Bigl[\int_{\TT^d} f(x)\,\rd x\Bigr] \\
    &\EE\Bigl[\int f(x)\,\rd x\Bigr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}



+1. As \EE appears to represent the expectations operator, one could also recommend replacing \newcommand{\EE}{\mathbf{E}} with \DeclareMathOperator{\EE}{\mathbf{E}}.

@Mico Possibly, yes.

@egreg Thanks for taking the time to point out all of the rest of your comments--I appreciate it.

@Mico Good point.
